# GCLogFileSize hotspot flag alrernative for openjdk15

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I have issues with openjdk-15 for linux. So, my app run with next setup

```
-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=tmp
-Xlog:gc:tmp/mygc.log
```

And I want to add limitations for GC logs via `-XX:GCLogFileSize`, but this HotSpot flag is not able for openjdk-15. Mb you know some alternative flags?

I've checked all available flags for my machine via `PrintFlagsFinal`, but don't find any relevant.

Comment: Note that Unified JVM Logging was added in Java 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most logging related flags were replaced with [Unified JVM Logging](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158).

Use `-Xlog` with `filesize` output option, e.g.

```
java -Xlog:gc:file=gc.txt:uptimemillis:filecount=5,filesize=1M
```

Comment: Why file is `gc.txt` (not `gc.log`)?

Comment: @SlandShow Put whatever name you like - this is just an example.